# How to get the name of the active app from the background app in iOS13 using Swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I want to get  the name of the active app from the background app in iOS13 using Swift 5. But I'm unable to find a place where such functionality is documented. Is it impossible to get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it impossible to get it?

Yes. You are sandboxed (unless you’ve jailbroken the device). You cannot learn what apps are running.